# Disconnecting a drive during a secure erase

Tags: hard-drive

If I issue the secure erase command to a hard drive can I disconnect the drive as long as it remains powered? I am thinking that since the erase is controlled by the HDD's internal controller it does not need to communicate with the PC.

Answer (score 3):

Doing so is outside the specification for most drive interfaces, so there's no reliable prediction on what will happen. The drive controller would be free, for example, to abort the secure erase command when it detects the control lines being disconnected, expecting a hot swap scenario with the power going away shortly afterwards.